# Combine the multiple Match Values in Excel

Tags: excel, match, concatenation

I want to combine Multiple Match Values in Excel [an illustrative picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-1FiuGK2JNZS1nWHdHVFNSaEE/view?usp=sharing)

the example is in the picture.

I want to concat the the match values in one cell

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How large is your data source ?

Are you considering VBA ?

If you need something quick and dirty, one way could be to use intermediate columns that will add item if they match a given ID.  
For example, if you have your data in column A and B, then column C could be based on `formula_in_C2 = IF(A2="v1",C1&B2,C1)`.
Expand the formula on the whole column.  The last row will give you what you are after.  Create similar columns for the other IDs.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Yes my data are large up then (10 000), I don't know how to use VBA, this method is good for just few set of data :)